# PySimpleGUI - not show background when window change

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

In my application I have multiple windows that change based on events(one close and another open)  and show only one window at a time. During one window close and another open its take some time since fetch data from database and prepare for window.

Here problem is that during the time of one window close and another open user can see and feel that one is being open and another is being close by seeing the background.

What I want, until second screen is not fully loaded, first window be visible on the screen.

My current code is something like,

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Button('Users', key='show_user_list')]]
window = sg.Window('users').Layout(layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event == 'show_user_list':
        window.Close()  
        # code ommited here for simplicity
        # do mysql stuff to fetch data
        # layout2 = ...
        # window2 = sg.Window('user listing').Layout(layout2)
        # while True:
        #   event, values = window2.Read()
        #   ...
        # like that I have multiple windows
    else:
        pass
```

How I can give users feel like the window content is changing not one window closes and another opens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can make sure the background is not seen by first opening your Window 2, which will be created on top of Window 1, THEN closing your Window 1.

To do this, add a `.Finalize()` onto the Window 2 creation.  This will cause the window to immediate show up.  Then on the next line, close Window 1.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Button('Users', key='show_user_list')]]
window = sg.Window('users').Layout(layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event == 'show_user_list':

        # code ommited here for simplicity
        # do mysql stuff to fetch data
        # layout2 = ...
        # window2 = sg.Window('user listing').Layout(layout2).Finalize()
        # window.Close() 
        # while True:
        #   event, values = window2.Read()
        #   ...
        # like that I have multiple windows
    else:
        pass
```

The key to making this kind of window update work is to create the windows at the same location.  The default is to make windows that are centered on the screen.  This means if your windows are not the same size then you'll likely notice a small "blip" as you change from one to the other.  But it shouldn't look bad because it'll happen so quickly.

If you really want to get fancy, you can add another step which will make the switch between the windows even smoother.  This new step involves creating window 2 with Alpha=0, meaning that it's invisible, then after it's fully formed (using `Finalize()`) you change the Alpha to 1 which will make the window appear.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('Example of window-replacement')],
          [sg.Combo(['abdeffg', 'rrrfwwew'], size=(10, 4))],
          [sg.B('Enable Filter'), sg.B('Warning'), sg.B('Reopen')],]

window = sg.Window('My Text Editor', layout)

while True:             # Event Loop
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None:
        break
    print(event, values)
    if event == 'Reopen':
        layout2 = [[sg.Text('This is a completely different window')],
                   [sg.Combo(['abdeffg', 'rrrfwwew'], size=(10, 4))],
                   [sg.B('Enable Filter'), sg.B('Warning'), sg.B('Reopen')], ]
        window2 = sg.Window('My Text Editor', layout2, alpha_channel=0).Finalize()
        window2.SetAlpha(1)
        window.Close()
        window = window2

window.Close()
```

This removed some of the "painting" of the window that I was seeing.  That shouldn't happen because I use this same trick when creating the window to begin with.  Alpha is used to hide the window while it's being created.